# Span tag in another span generates new line

Tags: html

Could you tell me how to avoid new line if `value.second` is present in file with `.tpl` extension? Or maybe use another tag?

```
 <span v-style font-color="secondary" font-type="caption-2"> {{ value.first | number }}
                                <span v-if="value.second "> - {{ value.second | number}}</span> m</span>
```

For now, if it's present I get new line

[image: screen showing new line]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`white-space:nowrap;` might be helpful. It will prevent inline break

```html
 <span v-style font-color="secondary" font-type="caption-2"> {{ value.first | number }} 
 <span v-if="value.second " style="white-space:nowrap"> - {{ value.second | number}}</span> m</span>
```

Comment: it needs to be added to first span, but ye, I need to use this style.